# How to validate date using PHP?

Tags: php, validation

I have small problem with date validation. It works if it only validates a day, not the whole date.

If, today is 21.07.2015, validation enables dates before the 21st of each month/each year. It should accept only dates starting from today.

Code is here:

```
   if (empty ($_POST['data'])) {
        $data_error = "You need to type a date";
        ++$error_counter;
    } elseif ($_POST['data'] < date("d.m.Y")) {
        $data_error = "You have chosen incorrect date";
        ++$error_counter;
    } else {
        $data = $_POST['data'];
    }
```

Comment: compare timestrings [int]  instead of strings ....

Comment: Regex is maybe needed here.

Comment: There's a perfectly good object in PHP designed specifically for dates... http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare by `strtotime()`

```
if (empty ($_POST['data'])) {
        $data_error = "You need to type a date";
        ++$error_counter;
    } elseif (strtotime($_POST['data']) < strtotime(date("d.m.Y"))) {
        $data_error = "You have chosen incorrect date";
        ++$error_counter;
    } else {
        $data = $_POST['data'];
    }
```